# Filtering a model by checking for presence in another model via ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django

Given the following two models:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class User(models.Model):
    owned_cards = models.ManyToManyField(Card)
```

Given a certain user, how can I, in one query, get all the Card objects that are not disabled, and are also present in that user's owned_cards field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, you can use the owned_cards field of a user object as a manager.

```
enabled_cards = theuser.owned_cards.filter(disabled=False)
```

Answer for the second question in the comments, this should work, using [Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to negate the lookup.

```
not_owned_cards = Card.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=theuser.owned_cards.all()), disabled=False)
```

Comment: Crap, ok, what if you want to get all the cards that are NOT present in the owned_cards field?